# Remove spaces before and after parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove one or more spaces **after** open parentheses and **before** close parentheses for both round and square parentheses.

```
$s = "This is ( a sample ) [ string ] to play with"
```

expected result:

```
"This is (a sample) [string] to play with"
```

I managed to remove the space **before**:

```
$s = preg_replace('/\s+(?=[\])])/', '', $s);
```

result:

```
"This is ( a sample) [ string] to play with"
```

but not the spaces **after** the parentheses!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=[([]) +| +(?=[)\]])
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG1bMg/2)**

Replace the matches with a blank string

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[([]) +` - matches 1+ occurrences of a space which are preceded by either a `[` or `(`
- `|` - OR
- `+(?=[)\]])` - matches 1+ occurrences of a space which are followed either by `)` or `]`

Comment: or three more characters even `[[(]\K +| +(?=[])])`  @ctwheels

Comment: @revo I was contemplating the same at first but I didn't like that it almost doubled the steps, so I settled for one character 

Comment: I was about to write the same thing

Comment: Don't rely on that numbers. Check Debugger steps. It actually reduces steps and it's obvious  @ctwheels