# Remove all spaces before and after parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove one or more spaces **before** and **after** any parentheses. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282015/remove-spaces-before-and-after-parentheses) where the issue has been solved for PHP with the following regex

```
(?<=[([]) +| +(?=[)\]])
```

now I would like to do the same in **Javascript** but Javascript regex engine does not have the same lookahead and lookbehind as PHP. I managed to make the following regex at least work in Javascript but it removes all spaces:

```
?![([]) +| +(?=[)\]])
```

See [Regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/yG1bMg/3).

**Given string:**

```
This is ( a sample     ) [           string ] to play with
```

**Expected result:**

```
This is (a sample) [string] to play with
```

Comment: @mplungjan. Not using regex.

Comment: What about `This is_____(___a sample___ )____ [___ string___ ]___ to play with` with `_` for a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use capturing groups instead and replace with their placeholders to restore the bracket/parentheses in the result:

```
.replace(/([([])\s+|\s+([)\]])/g, "$1$2");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG1bMg/4)

**Details**

- `([([])\s+` - Group 1 capturing either a `(` or a `[` (referred to with `$1` from the string replacement pattern) and then 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s+([)\]])` - 1+ whitespaces followed with a `)` or `]` captured into Group 2 (referred to with `$2` from the string replacement pattern)

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['This is ( a sample ) [ string ] to play with', 
            'This is ( a sample     ) [           string] to play with'];
var rx = /([([])\s+|\s+([)\]])/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s+ " =>\n"+ s.replace(rx, "$1$2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function Do(){
    console.log(document.querySelector("input").value
        .replace(/\s*?\s([\[\(])\s*/g, " $1").replace(/\s*([\)\]])(\s?)\s*/g, "$1$2"));
}
```

```html
<b>Type Your String Here:</b>
<input type='text' style='width:300px' value="This is   (    a sample  )    [         string  ]   to play with"/>

<input type='button' onclick="Do();" value="Start!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by using Positive lookaheads and a simple replace.

```
.replace(/(?<=[\(|\[])\s+|\s+(?=[\]|\)])/g, '');
```

ex.

```js
const currentString = 'This is ( a sample     ) [           string ] to play with';
const regex = /(?<=[\(|\[])\s+|\s+(?=[\]|\)])/g;

console.log(currentString.replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: Have you run your snippet? I don't think so.

Comment: @Toto? I have run it and it returns the expected output. "This is (a sample) [string] to play with"

Comment: When I click on "Run code snippet" I got and error `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group"`